# How to define lighter/darker color from already defined color in TeX?

Tags: color

I am new in TeX, so question may be little silly.  Is any chance to use already defined color to define new color which will be darkner or lighter? I want to use only TeX. So i have defined color like this:

```
\def\mainColor{\pdfliteral{0.1 0.5 1 rg}}
```

How i define new color (lighter) from this color?

Comment: Welcome to TeX-sx! TeX itself doesn't know anything about colours, which is left to the driver system. In your example you are using a PDF mode special to set a PDF colour. I'm not really sure what you actually want: can't you just add a second colour definition?

Comment: Why are you using pdfliterals (which restricts your document to pdftex) rather than an existing set of color macros for plain, or better a more complete format such as latex or context?

Comment: Thanks for explanation. I want to have main color, which will defined other colors, like theme. I dont want to use latex.

Comment: yes but colour has been used for decades with tex and there are many extensive sets of macros giving features, why are you directly using a tex primitive to inject literal pdf? If you do do that your question isn't about tex, simply about pdf color syntax

Comment: Do you mean perhaps that you want to define a main colour and one or more secondary ones in one go using some relative specification? For example, 'take the main RGB values and make the colour lighter by X percent'?

Comment: Joseph Wright: Yes, that i meant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using colors directly by `\pdfliteral` as mentioned in your post and only in the form `num num num rg` then the `\defdarker` should be defined. The usage is `\defdarker\newColor\oriColor{coefficient}`. The macro `\oriColor` must be defined already as `\pdfliteral{num1 num2 num3 rg}` and `\defdarker` defines `\newColor` as `\pdfliteral{c*num1 c*num2 c*num3 rg}` where `nums` are multiplied by the coefficient `c`. It means that `\defdarker\newColor\oriColor{.5}` sets the new color darker (multiplying .5 by all light sources from RGB).

```
{\lccode`\?=`\p \lccode`\!=`\t  \lowercase{\gdef\ignorept#1?!{#1}}}
\newdimen\tmpdim
\def\defdarker#1#2#3{\expandafter\defdarkerA#2#1{#3}}
\def\defdarkerA#1#2{\defdarkerB#2\end}
\def\defdarkerB#1 #2 #3 #4\end#5#6{%
   \tmpdim=#1pt \tmpdim=#6\tmpdim
   \edef\tmp{\expandafter\ignorept\the\tmpdim}%
   \tmpdim=#2pt \tmpdim=#6\tmpdim
   \edef\tmp{\tmp\space \expandafter\ignorept\the\tmpdim}%
   \tmpdim=#3pt \tmpdim=#6\tmpdim
   \edef\tmp{\tmp\space \expandafter\ignorept\the\tmpdim}%
   \edef#5{\pdfliteral{\tmp\space rg}}%
}

\def\Black{\pdfliteral{0 g}}
\def\mainColor{\pdfliteral{0.1 0.5 1 rg}}

\defdarker\newColor\mainColor{.5}
\defdarker\darkColor\newColor{.5}

\mainColor AAA
\newColor  BBB
\darkColor CCC
\Black

\end
```

The problem is that this color manipulation works only locally on pages, i. e. color have to be set and reset to the `\Black` at the same page. If you really are using plain TeX then I recommend to use OPmac macro package where colors are implemented. But the `\defdarker` macro for OPmac's color management will be slight different. Maybe I will add this to my [OPmac-tricks](http://petr.olsak.net/opmac-tricks-e.html) page.

Answer (score 11):

[image]

If you use `\pdfliteral` then TeX just passes the string straight to pdf so the question resolves to one of pdf color syntax. here I make a variant by halving the difference between the rgb components and 1 (white) to make a lighter shade.

If you instead use a developed existing macro set such as xcolor, a more natural syntax is possible to blend colours, here I just mix with white and black, and also you are then not restricted to pdftex, and the same syntax will work with tex/dvips or xetex.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\def\mainColor{\pdfliteral{0.1 0.5 1 rg}}
\def\subColor{\pdfliteral{.55 .75 1 rg}}

\definecolor{maincolor}{rgb}{0.1,0.5,1}
\definecolor{black}{rgb}{0,0,0}

\begin{document}


{\mainColor one two three}

{\subColor one two three}

\bigskip

\textcolor{maincolor}{one two three}

\textcolor{maincolor!50}{one two three}


\textcolor{maincolor!50!black!50}{one two three}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why do you redefine black? Just to ensure it is using `rgb`?

Comment: @cfr yes (although actually I think xcolor would take care of that)

Comment: IMHO, mixing colors directly defined by `\pdfliteral` with the colors from `xcolor` package (using pdfcolorstack and `\aftergroup` technique) cannot be recommended. For example the group braces in your code `{\mainColor one two three}` are irrelevant here because `\pdfliteral` sets color independent of the TeX groups.

Comment: @wipet I agree. You would never use these two mechanisms in the same document. I just put them next to each other for ease of posting and to show xcolor was making the same color as the OPs example. Yes I known the grouping is spurious but (I hope) the OPs unshown code is doing something about providing support for that.

Answer (score 11):

This is an extension of [David Carlisle's `xcolor` solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/229449/) which shows how to use `\colorlet` to define additional shades for convenience.

[image: shades of main]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{maincolor}{rgb}{0.1,0.5,1}
\colorlet{lightmain}{maincolor!75}
\colorlet{lightermain}{maincolor!50}
\colorlet{lightestmain}{maincolor!25}
\colorlet{darkmain}{maincolor!75!black}
\colorlet{darkermain}{maincolor!50!black}
\colorlet{darkestmain}{maincolor!25!black}

\begin{document}

\textcolor{darkestmain}{one two three}

\textcolor{darkermain}{one two three}

\textcolor{darkmain}{one two three}

\textcolor{maincolor}{one two three}

\textcolor{lightmain}{one two three}

\textcolor{lightermain}{one two three}

\textcolor{lightestmain}{one two three}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

More a long comment than an answer. For gradations of a custom color, say "`thecolor`", the simplest is not define more and more names of variations of `thecolor` that anybody cannot  remember, but simply use percentages of that color, like `thecolor!75`.

Think in a fade out or a transition to another color of say...ten colors. Are you able to find the right name for each tone? But in this way is very easy :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{thecolor}{rgb}{0.1,0.5,1}

\begin{document}

\textcolor{black}{one two three}  

\textcolor{thecolor!25!black}{one two three} 

\textcolor{thecolor!50!black}{one two three} 

\textcolor{thecolor!75!black}{one two three} 

\textcolor{thecolor}{one two three} 

\textcolor{thecolor!75}{one two three} 

\textcolor{thecolor!50}{one two three}

\textcolor{thecolor!25}{one two three}

\textcolor{green}{one two three}

\textcolor{thecolor!25!green}{one two three}

\textcolor{thecolor!50!green}{one two three}

\textcolor{thecolor!75!green}{one two three}

\textcolor{thecolor}{one two three}

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE]