# Multiplication by decimal numbers in TeX macro?

Tags: plain-tex

How can i multiple variable by decimal number? I have this code:

```
\newcount\tempArgument
\def\headerColor#1{
   \tempArgument = #1
   \multiply\tempArgument by 0.75
   \defcolor\tmp\mainColor{\tempArgument} \tmp
}
```

I want to have in \tempArgument first argument multiplied by some constant. I want to use only plain TeX, not LaTeX.

Comment: do you want `\tempArgument` to be a count register (so will have to round to nearest integer to multiply by .75) or do you want the answer in a macro (which can hold the decimal digits). Why plain rather than latex, most people use a rather more complete format for documents than plain. latex or context or something.

Comment: I want to have in \tempArgument numbers like 1.5, 1.2 and so on. There will no be number larger then 5, most of time there will be from interval 0-2. Latex is too complicated if you have specific needs and do not want to read documentation with hundred of pages. I want to have everything under my control and well explained.

Comment: What does `\defcolor` do?

Comment: Define new color from existing color multiplied by number in RGB.

Comment: @Novros: And where does this magnificent `defcolor` command come from? ;-)

Comment: @Novros *How* does it operate? TeX has no floating point registers, they can only be emulated, to a certain extent, with `\dimen` registers. However, the `fp` package can work also with Plain TeX, IIRC.

Comment: @Novros  so `\tempArgumnent` can not be defined by `\newcount` if you want it to have values like 1.5.  "under your control and well explained" comes to "not existing and having to do it all your self". color mixing and integrating colour into tex's box mode is available in well tested macro sets for any format this is intended to be used for document production rather than educational examples.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer It comes from this question http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/229445/how-to-define-lighter-darker-color-from-already-defined-color-in-tex. And i see, it use emulation of dim variables to get floating point numbers.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle In my opinion is good to have own macros (more simplier to use) than macros, with more arguments which i will never user and are useless for me. But of course i doing it for education reasons.

Comment: @Novros but color and arithmetic macros are not going to have lots of arguments, learning to write your own is good but in a real document it's better to use some that have been debugged and tested in millions of documents over the last few decades.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I know, that is good to use debugged things for real documents. That is reason why i use LaTeX in projects. But almost always i did not understand how it works or why i must do this or that.

Comment: @David: Why LaTeX rather than Microsoft Word, most people use a rather more complete program for documents than LaTeX. `;-P`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This shows the calculation 5 * .75

```
> \tempArgument=macro:
->3.75.
\headerColor ...the \dimen 0 }\show \tempArgument 

l.15 \headerColor{5}
```

From

```
\begingroup
\lccode`\:`\p
\lccode`\;`\t
\lowercase{\endgroup\def\strippt#1:;}{#1}

\def\headerColor#1{
   \dimen0 = #1pt
   \dimen0=0.75\dimen0
   \edef\tempArgument{\expandafter\strippt\the\dimen0 }%
   \show\tempArgument
}


\headerColor{5}

\bye
```